# How do collimation films work?

Tags: optics, visible-light

I work in machine vision and in the last few years cheap collimated backlights have become widely available. Before, you had to buy huge telecentric illuminators to get that effect, but these days a not-as-great-but-still-very-good solution is available in the form of a standard backlight (a bunch of flatly arranged LEDs with a very diffuse diffuser in front of them) with a collimation film in front of it. But for the life of me, I can't find any information on how this collimation film works.

Does anyone here know anything about this magical material that makes my life easier?

An example of the film I'm talking about:
https://www.effilux.com/en/products/accessories/optical/collimation

Comment: Is this the same as [optical lighting film](https://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/1132683O/3mtm-optical-lighting-film-2405.pdf)? (link is a pdf).

Comment: I don't know the answer, but maybe it's made of the same stuff as a "privacy screen protector" that you can stick on a phone or computer screen to stop people from reading over your shoulder.

Comment: @JohnRennie I'm not sure that's the film because it seems to act as a mirror for small angles of incidence while letting through and diverting higher angles. Seems like the opposite of what a "collimation film" is supposed to be doing. But I guess it could be a similar principle - a bunch of small prisms and/or lenses or something.

Comment: Apparently 3M makes brightness enhancement films which are "Suitable for applications that can tolerate a reduction in viewing cone to
achieve higher brightness." Sounds exactly like the mystical "collimation film". Confusingly, in pictures it looks exactly like the optical lighting film: just a bunch of thin long prisms. (I found it here: https://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/977332O/display-materials-systems-strategies-for-large-displays.pdf)